# Trying to examine contents of a variable with if/else in Ruby

Tags: ruby, linux

I am using the following code to check if a process is running using ps and grep and storing the PID in a variable.

Then I am checking if there is a value within that variable with an if/else statement. The goal is to run whats in the if block if the condition is true and if not, execute what is in else

```
fisheye_pid = `ps -ef | grep fisheyeboot | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`
kill_fisheye = `kill #{fisheye_pid}`

if "#{fisheye_pid}" != nil or 0
  puts ''
  puts  '--------------------'
  puts '|  Stopping Fisheye  |'
  puts  '--------------------'
  puts kill_fisheye
  sleep(5)
    if "#{fisheye_pid}" == nil or 0
      puts 'Fisheye has been stopped..'
      puts ''
    end
else
  puts 'Fisheye is not running, proceeding.'

end
```

If anything sticks out let me know. Its probably something small i am overlooking.

Comment: correction, i want to run the if block if the condition is NOT true.

Comment: a couple things stand out to me: the second half of the if condition should be fisheye_pid == 0, not just 0. Also, there is a difference between or and the traditional ||, just so you know. Another point: after your sleep, fisheye_pid will not change. You need to reassign in, as in copy the line where it is assigned. Does that make sense? If you like I can write up an answer.

Comment: What do you mean by fisheye_pid == 0 not just 0? I have it set to nil or 0.

Also it does make sense.. So after the sleep and before the nested if statement I would run: "puts fisheye_pid"

Comment: in order to reassign the variable to a more accurate/current representation?

Comment: For the first conditional: the 0 after the or will always evaluate to false because you aren't comparing it to anything. Just because you have fisheye_pid != nil in the first part doesn't mean that 0 gets compared to fisheye_pid automatically, you have to type it out again. It should be:
 ```if fisheye_pid != nil or fisheye_pid == 0```
 As for the nested conditional, you are correct, it needs to be reevaluated exactly as you said.

Comment: Ok, After some reading, I will use || vs or. I will also refresh the value of fisheye_pid after the sleep and adjust the first if statement.

Thank you!

Comment: Another note, just for style points, it might be worth creating a method called ```fisheye_pid``` that runs ````ps -ef | grep fisheyeboot | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'````. I say this because you are currently resetting the value of a variable, whereas you could just call a method that returns the status and save the mess of printing ````ps -ef | grep fisheyeboot | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'```` twice. Make sense?

Comment: "or" will always take precedence and is really like splitting the line in half - in ten years I've rarely seen it used at all.  because 0 is not-falsy "or 0" will always return true..  Try to always use || and don't be afraid of parentheses

Comment: What do you want to achieve with `"#{fisheye_pid}"`? `fisheye_pid` is already a string, so it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Kills process "fisheyeboot"**

```
fisheye_pid = `ps -ef | grep fisheyeboot | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`.to_i

if fisheye_pid > 0
  puts ''
  puts  '--------------------'
  puts '|  Stopping Fisheye  |'
  puts  '--------------------'
  `kill #{fisheye_pid}`
  # TODO: sleep 5 seconds and recheck process by running "ps" again
else
  puts 'Fisheye is not running, proceeding.'
end
```

---

You could also just use `killall` and discard the output:

```
`killall fisheyeboot`
```

Comment: I think the op wants to wait 5 seconds and recheck the value of fisheye_pid.

Comment: You're right. I was hoping to keep the answer clean by just implementing enough to point him in the right direction

Comment: Thanks guys this has given me tons to improve off of.

Comment: I got the logic to work, but when the process wasnt running to begin with it prints Terminated instead of what I have in my puts "fisheye isnt running" under the else statement

Comment: Why is it printing "Terminated"?  Is that something you added to your program? Did it print "Stopping Fisheye" too?